# Controlling User Access in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

What is the standard practice in Meteor for controlling users access for certain sensitive pages? For example, only users with `Admin` level can access CRUD operations, so what is the best method to block/allow users access these pages?

I know that we can use `publish` to limit the user accessibility to data, but for pages, what is the best way?

I am thinking of checking the user level during the rendered but again, I am not sure if this method is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **currently** no method of denying access to a **page,** as the whole client code is packed and sent as one application. Since the code for restricted page is in the browser, user can access the page easily.

What you can do is to restrict access to **data** displayed on those pages. There are two things to be done:

- Specify what data the user can **see.** This is done via the [publish and subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe) methods. In the `Meteor.publish` method you can check user privileges and decide which objects user can see, and which fields of those objects.
- Specify what data the user can **change.** This, as stated in the other answer, is achieved by [`Collection.allow`](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) and [`Collection.deny`](http://docs.meteor.com/#deny) methods, which allow you to check user privileges on each CRUD operation and decide whether it's allowed.

Comment: Understood. However, do I have to add the user level (like admin, superadmin, etc) in the user profile object or there is other way around it?

Comment: You can add it however you want, ideally outside of the `profile` subdocument, as it's user-editable by default.

Answer (score 2):

The only places you need to control the user's level are in publish and in allow/deny callbacks. By controlling it in publish, you make sure the user does not receive any information it shouldn't know, and by controlling it in allow/deny callbacks, you make sure the user does not add/edit/delete information it's not allowed to.

If you're using custom methods for CRUD operations (on the server), this is a third place where you need to control the user's level (allow/deny callbacks are only checked against CUD operations made on the clients!).

**Edit**

For examples on how to use the allow callback, see http://docs.meteor.com/#allow The deny callback works in a similar (but opposite) way. At least one allow callback must return `true` and all deny callbacks must return `false` in order for operation to be granted.

Comment: @PeppeLG Do you mind show me some example for the allow deny callbacks. Does that mean the pages are controlled through allow/deny callbacks and the data through the publish. Do I get this correctly?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha With "pages", I assume you mean something like the way it works in Iron Router? You can't protect pages (and there's no points in doing that neither!), all you really need to protect is the data, and you protect it through the ways I described above. I'll update the post with some examples.